# Ubuntu React and SSL

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, ssl, https

I wrote a simple service that runs on the local network on React on Ubuntu server 20.04.
Since the clipboard is used there, I had to launch it via HTTPS

I created a certificate with these parameters:

```
    [ req ]
    default_bits       = 4096
    distinguished_name = subject
    req_extensions     = x509_ext
    prompt             = no
    
    [ subject ]
    countryName         = UA
    stateOrProvinceName     = Kyiv
    localityName            = Kyiv
    organizationName         = ORGNAME
    commonName          = 192.168.0.188
    emailAddress            = myadress@domaine.com
    
    [ x509_ext ]
    basicConstraints        = CA:TRUE
    subjectAltName          = IP:192.168.0.188
```

I added it to the client root centers, chrome still complains about it, tell me what else I can do so that chrome doesn’t burning up red